# Excel - Count total number of times a text occurs in rows based on criteria in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of data, for example:

| Name | Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | Apple | Apple |  |
| James | Orange |  |  |
| Thomas | Apple | Orange |  |
| Thomas | Orange | Orange |  |
| Peter | Apple | Orange | Banana |
| Peter | Banana |  |  |

I want to count the number of times an item appears in the whole table based on the person's name, i.e. James Apple=2, James Orange=1, Thomas Orange=3, Peter Banana=2 etc.

I've tried some formulas such as `=COUNTIF(INDEX(B:D,MATCH("Thomas",A:A,0),0),"Orange")` but it would only return the count of the first row, in this case 1.

A regular countif i.e. `=COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"Thomas",B2:D7,"Orange")` would only work for one column, so this would return a value error. I suppose I could do multiple countifs for Row B/C/D and add them together if the dataset is small like so:

| Name | Item | Count1 | Count2 | Count3 | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | Apple | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| James | Orange | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| James | Banana | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Thomas | Apple | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Thomas | Orange | 1 | 2 | 0 | 3 |
| Thomas | Banana | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Peter | Apple | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Peter | Orange | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Peter | Banana | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

But is there a formula to find the total counts in a single cell/column instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another alternative which does it with one single dynamic array formula with one input, using `GROUPBY()` function (available for `MS365` users in `Beta` channel).

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _data, A2:D7,
     _name, TAKE(_data,,1),
     _items, DROP(_data,,1),
     _merged, HSTACK(TOCOL(IFS(_items<>"",_name),2),TOCOL(_items,1)),
     _output, GROUPBY(_merged,TAKE(_merged,,-1),COUNTA,0,0,2),
     VSTACK({"Name","Items","Sum"},_output))
```

---

If you don't have access to `GROUPBY()` then you may the one shown below as well:

```
=LET(
     _data, A2:D7,
     _name, TAKE(_data,,1),
     _items, DROP(_data,,1),
     _merged, HSTACK(TOCOL(IFS(_items<>"",_name),2),TOCOL(_items,1)),
     _uniqm, UNIQUE(_merged),
     _counts, MMULT(N((TAKE(_uniqm,,1)=TOROW(TAKE(_merged,,1)))*(TAKE(_uniqm,,-1)=TOROW(TAKE(_merged,,-1)))),SEQUENCE(ROWS(_merged),,,0)),
     HSTACK(_uniqm,_counts))
```

---

This can also be accomplished using `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Itemtbl`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Itemtbl"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Name"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Name", "Value"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Name", Order.Ascending}, {"Value", Order.Ascending}, {"Count", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Or, Using `MAP()`

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _data, A2:D7,
     _name, TAKE(_data,,1),
     _items, DROP(_data,,1),
     _merged, HSTACK(TOCOL(IFS(_items<>"",_name),2),TOCOL(_items,1)),
     _uniqm, UNIQUE(_merged),
     HSTACK(_uniqm,
     MAP(TAKE(_uniqm,,1),TAKE(_uniqm,,-1),LAMBDA(x,y,SUM((x=$A$2:$A$7)*(y=$B$2:$D$7))))))
```

---

Bit shorter method:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _data, TOCOL(IFS(B2:D7<>"",A2:A7&"|"&B2:D7),2),
     _uniq, UNIQUE(_data),
     _count, MAP(TAKE(_uniq,,1),TAKE(_uniq,,-1),LAMBDA(x,y,SUM((x=TAKE(_data,,1))*(TAKE(_data,,-1)=y)))),
     HSTACK(TEXTBEFORE(_uniq,"|"),TEXTAFTER(_uniq,"|"),_count))
```

---

Comment: Haven't seen any of those formulas to be honest, but pretty amazed that it can be expanded as required easily. Thanks!

Comment: That said my actual dataset is much larger and both this and the sumproduct formula results in an error (insufficient resources to calculate), so seems like I might need to do countifs on each column and add them up.

Comment: @jerryl then one better option is to use `Power Query` here. let me update my post. `PQ` will be flexible and quicker.

Comment: @jerryl posted few other ways, using `PQ` will be faster than any, and then two methods using `MAP()` the logic remains same per say. Your feedback is important for me, let me know if that works and if you face any issues yet again

Comment: Worked like magic, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the SUMPRODUCT function along with COUNTIF. Here's a formula you can use:

Assuming your data starts from A1, and the item you want to count is in cell E1 (for example, "Apple"), you can use the following formula in F2 and drag it down:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$10="James")*(B$2:D$10="Apple"))+
 SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$10="Thomas")*(B$2:D$10="Apple"))+
 SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$10="Peter")*(B$2:D$10="Apple"))
```